# Jquery validate messages & rules not working for all fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to add more than 2 rules and messages, But its not working..

```
$("#updateMemberProfileForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            },rules: {
                "member.memberphone" : {
                    required: true,
                    phoneUS: true
                },
                "member.memberfirstname" : {
                    required: true
                },
                "member.memberlastname" : {
                    required: true
                },
                "member.membermiddlename" : {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                "member.memberphone" : {
                    required: " * Phone no. required"
                },
                "member.memberfirstname" : {
                    required: " * firstname required"
                },
                "member.memberlastname" : {
                    required: " * lastname required"
                },
                "member.membermiddlename" : {
                    required: "* middlename required"
                }
            },
            errorElement: "span"
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
$("#AdditionalDetailsForm").validate({
        rules: {
            ignore: ":not(:visible)",
            Account_Number: {
                required: true
            },
            BaseJurisdiction: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Account_Number: {
                required: "<br/> Please enter the field"
            },
            BaseJurisdiction: {
                required: "<br/> Please enter the field"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what  does   ignore: ":not(:visible)",   do?   and  can i have more than two rules i.e,  account_number, basejuristiction & more...?

Comment: sure you can add multiple rules.. :not(:visible) is for validating only visible fields or elements... in case u r hiding any field means it can't be validated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed something in messages. Here is the code..

```
$("#updateMemberProfileForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            },rules: {
                "member.memberphone" : {
                    required: true,
                    phoneUS: true
                },
                "member.memberfirstname" : {
                    required: true
                },
                "member.memberlastname" : {
                    required: true
                },
                "member.membermiddlename" : {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                "member.memberphone" : {
                    required: " * Phone no. required",
                    phoneUS : "* Enter valid phone no."
                },
                "member.memberfirstname" : {
                    required: " * firstname required"
                },
                "member.memberlastname" : {
                    required: " * lastname required"
                },
                "member.membermiddlename" : {
                    required: "* middlename required"
                }
            },
            errorElement: "span"
        });
```

Comment: In rules its  phoneUS  and in messages its  phoneUs ..  which one works?

Comment: phoneUS only works... then it checks any message for phoneUS .. rules and messages should be same field..